# TOMEE Exclude A JAR

Tags: java, apache, apache-tomee

I am trying to figure out how to have TOMEE exclude a particular JAR.

I am following the instructions defined [here](http://tomee.apache.org/application-discovery-via-the-classpath.html).

---

According to the doc, it looks like I should be able to exclude the file by setting this property in `{TOMEE}/conf/system.properties` ::

```
openejb.deployments.classpath.exclude=/opt/tomee/apps/My_Expanded_EAR/Jar_File_I_Want_To_Exclude.jar
```

---

But when doing this, my JAR is still getting loaded.

Has anybody ever experienced this before?

Answer (score 1):

first this classpath deployment is for embedded mode not standalone mode and there is an easier solution today: exclude the jar name (prefix matching actually). It can be done in conf/exclusions.list or WEB-INF/exclusions.list.

Just set the content of the file to:

```
# inherit from defaults, this is important to keep it
default-list
# add custom ones
Jar_File_I_Want_To_Exclude
```

Alternatively you can set your custom extension in conf/system.properties using:

```
openejb.additional.exclude = Jar_File_I_Want_To_Exclude1,Jar_File_I_Want_To_Exclude2,...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I will give that a try hopefully sometime today and post my results.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "prefix matching"?

I tried this ::
`default-list`
`calculation-svc-`

and ::
`default-list`
`calculation-svc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

but either way, classes from that JAR are still getting picked up.

Comment: I can see from the catalina log that it's trying to load classpath exclusions, but it doesn't seem like it's actually finding any.

Not sure why it looks like it's doing it twice.


`Jun 15, 2016 2:32:22 PM org.apache.openejb.config.NewLoaderLogic getExclusions`

`INFO: Loaded classpath exclusions from: C:\Applications\tomee\conf\exclusions.list`

`Jun 15, 2016 2:32:22 PM org.apache.openejb.config.NewLoaderLogic getExclusions`

`INFO: Loaded classpath exclusions from: C:\Applications\tomee\conf\exclusions.list`

Comment: It can do it twice under some circumstances and shouldn't be an issue

"prefix-matching" means the test for each line is "startsWith" on the file name (ensure to not have a hidden character or space at the end). it typically allows to skip the version and extension from the list

configuring logs in debug mode should gives you more info